# Assign an accessable (from code) nickname variable for each git remote when pushing

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I have a certain project, basically, that consists of single javascript file. It's like a worker, it receives task data from message queue, runs the task and sends back data. It runs on `NodeJS` backend (on digitalocean with dokku).

I have a `git` repository for this project. I am pushing it to, lets say, 10 different remotes so that I have 10 workers waiting for orders, each ready to run a task.

In order to monitor all 10 workers activity I am using message queue based logging, that, basically, pushes all log messages to queue, and then some other program just stores received log messages somewhere.

By having 10 different worker I somehow have to **know exactly** what worker produced the message. The idea of hardcoding worker names in their code will fail, I suppose.
So maybe there is a way to define for each git remote a nickname variable (or pass directly the name of remote), pass it somehow during the `git push remote_#` so it could be accessible from worker's code?

In other words, can I do something like this:

```
git push remote_1 master callsign="worker alpha"
git push remote_2 master callsign="worker beta"
git push remote_3 master callsign="worker gamma"
...
```

and then inside worker's code call logging by adding:

```
console.log( callsign, "said this log message" );
```

Is there a best practice advice for that kind of situations?